# Feynman diagrams position in the text

Tags: feynman, feynmf, document

I'm trying to draw two Feynman diagrams and the definition of the objects changes its form.

```
\begin{figure}[htp!]
\hspace{1.5cm}
\subfloat[ \\ diagram 1.]{ 

\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(150,60)
    \fmfstraight
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}
    \fmfright{o1,h,o2}
    % gluons
    \fmf{gluon}{i1,t1}
    \fmf{gluon}{t2,i2}
    \fmf{phantom,tension=0.5}{t1,o1}
    \fmf{phantom,tension=0.5}{t2,o2}
    \fmffreeze
    % top loop
    \fmf{fermion,tension=1}{t1,t2,t3,t1}
    % Higgs boson
    \fmf{dashes,tension=2.0}{t3,h}
    % labels
    \fmflabel{$g$}{i1}
    \fmflabel{$g$}{i2}
    \fmflabel{H}{h}
  \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}

}
\hspace{1.5cm}
\subfloat[\\diagram 2.]{

\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(120,60)
    %\fmfstraight
    \fmfleft{i1,i3} 
    \fmfright{o1,o2,o3}
    \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
    \fmf{fermion}{i3,v3,o3}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmf{boson,label=,label.side=left}{v3,v2,v1}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmf{dashes}{v2,o2}
    \fmflabel{$q$}{i3}
    \fmflabel{$q'$}{i1}
    \fmflabel{H}{o2}
  \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}

}

\caption{diagrams.}
\label{fig:017}
\end{figure}
```

for some reason the figures are confused with each other

[image]

what i want to get is:

[image]

Comment: You've used `\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}` for both drawings, so the second drawing would overwrite the first. Try giving them different names e.g. `feyngraph1` and `feyngraph2`.

Comment: Or just use a single \begin{fmffile} around the entire document. Multiple images can be in the same file.